# SQL Server Costs

Tags: sql-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I`ve been looking on the web for quite a long time to find out the pricing for SQL Server. Microsoft makes you browse for a long time until you find some piece of info. Could some one please show me the link for the pricing?

Answer (score 2):

This link should answer your questions about pricing:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server/how-to-buy.aspx

You may also find some pricing differences through your local Microsoft reseller.

Comment: Only Microsoft would need a 12 page guide on how their licensing works!

Answer (score 2):

You need to contact a reseller and ask for pricing, not Microsoft. The best Microsoft could do is give you MSRP numbers which they very rarely do in my experience. At worst, search the websites of major resellers like CDW, Insight or whatever is major in your part of the world for prices.

Example from CDW: http://www.cdw.com/shop/search/software-titles/microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2.aspx